# AWS Terraform target group for vpc endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, terraform, endpoint

How can I create a target group for a network load balancer containing a VPC endpoint in Terraform?
In AWS console, I would have done following steps:

- Create VPC Endpoint in two subnets to an endpoint service in another VPC
- Create a target group of type IP and register the IP adresses of 
  the enpoints created in step 1

In terraform, I can create target groups and endpoints, but I don't know how to assign the enpoint's IPs to the target group. Where can I find instructions or an example how to do this? (Creating target groups for type instance is no problem, my question is specific for type IP).

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Comment: This the same question I have asked here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64111177/terraform-how-to-register-known-private-ip-address-in-target-group-of-type-ip. may I know I you resolved it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use datasource `aws_network_interface` to retrieve private IPs of yours VPC endpoints and describe it in target group like that:

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "vpc_endpoint" {
  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"
  ...
}

data "aws_network_interface" "nics" {
  for_each = aws_vpc_endpoint.vpc_endpoint.network_interface_ids

  id = each.key
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "this" {
  for_each = data.aws_network_interface.nics

  target_id        = each.value.private_ip
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.this.arn
  port             = 443
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code.
In case someone is using the Terraform registry modules:

```
data "aws_network_interface" "apigw_endpoint_ip" {
          for_each = module.endpoints.endpoints["api-gateway"].network_interface_ids
          id       = each.value
        }


module "alb" {
  source             = "terraform-aws-modules/alb/aws"
  version            = "8.7.0"
  name               = "New-ALB"
  internal           = true
  load_balancer_type = var.alb_type
  vpc_id             = module.base_network.vpc_id
  subnets            = [module.base_network.private_subnets[0], module.base_network.private_subnets[1], module.base_network.private_subnets[2]]
  target_groups = [{
    name             = "New-API-GW-TG"
    backend_protocol = "HTTPS"
    backend_port     = 443
    health_check = {
      enabled             = true
      interval            = 10
      path                = "/"
      port                = "traffic-port"
      healthy_threshold   = 2
      unhealthy_threshold = 2
      timeout             = 5
      protocol            = "HTTPS"
      matcher             = "200"
    }
    target_type = "ip"
    targets = {
      target_1 = {
        target_id = element([for a in data.aws_network_interface.apigw_endpoint_ip : a.private_ip], 0)
        port      = 443
      },
      target_2 = {
        target_id = element([for a in data.aws_network_interface.apigw_endpoint_ip : a.private_ip], 1)
        port      = 443
      },
      target_3 = {
        target_id = element([for a in data.aws_network_interface.apigw_endpoint_ip : a.private_ip], 2)
        port      = 443
      }
    }
  }]
  tags = local.tags
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Late to the party! But this is what I did.

Created a null resource that would get the IP addresses of the [VPC endpoints](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/vpc_endpoint) and store it in a file

```
resource "null_resource" "nlb" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "dig +short ${lookup(tomap(element(aws_vpc_endpoint.api-gw.dns_entry, 0)), "dns_name", "")} > /tmp/entry"
  }
}
```

and then read the file entries

```
resource aws_lb_target_group_attachment nlb {
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.nlb
  ]

  for_each = toset(slice(split("\n", file("/tmp/entry")), 0, 2)) 

  target_group_arn = resource.aws_lb_target_group.nlb.arn
  target_id = each.value
  port = 443
}
```