# Terraform how to register known private ip address in target group of type "ip"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In Terraform

How can register known private ip addresses in target group of type "ip". Below is my current code.

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "default" {
  name        = "target group name"
  port        = var.container_port
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id      = data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.vpc_id

  health_check {
    path     = var.health_check_path
    protocol = "HTTP"
    port     = var.target_group_port
    interval = 60
  }

  tags = var.tags
 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You use [aws_lb_target_group_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_target_group_attachment) for that.

For example:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "test" {
  target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.default.arn
  target_id        = instance-ip-address
  port             = 80
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not: `target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.default.arn`, but instead:

```
target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.default.arn
```